# Postfix Evaluation code Using Stack

Tags: c++, postfix-notation

I have final exam tomorrow in data structures 'LAB'!

I have a Problem when I run this code!
This code evaluates the postfix expression. It's so simple..but i don't know why when I run it and try to divide e.g : 6/2.      it prints out 2 instead of 3!

The + and - and * all are correct but the problem with division! Do you think the problem with library in my compiler!!

I use Code::Blocks and Visual C++.

Could you Please help me with this! :(

---

The Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define stacksize 6
struct stacktype{
  float data[stacksize];
  int top;
};

void push( stacktype*s, float d){
  if ( s->top < 6) {
    s->data[s->top]=d;
    s->top++;
  }
}

float pop(stacktype*s){
  if ( s->top != 0){
    s->top--;
    return s->data[s->top];
  }
  return 0;
}

float oper(char symbol, float op1, float op2){
  switch (symbol){
    case '+': return (op1+op2);break;
    case '-':return (op1-op2);break;
    case '*':return (op1*op2);break;
    case '/':return (op1/op2);break;
    default: cout<<"illegal operation.......\n";
}

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  float op1,op2,symb,value;
  char symbol;
  stacktype *s;
  s= new stacktype;
  s->top=0;
  cout<<"Enter The Postfix Expression To Evaluate::  \n\n";
  cin>>symbol;
  while ( symbol != '.') {
   if ( symbol == '+' || symbol == '-' || symbol == '*' || symbol == '/'){
   op2=pop(s);
   op1=pop(s);
   value=oper(symbol,op1,op2);
   push(s,value);
 }
 else {
   if ( symbol == '0') symb =0 ;
   else if ( symbol == '1') symb = 1;
   else if ( symbol == '2') symb =2 ;
   else if ( symbol == '3') symb =3 ;
   else if ( symbol == '4') symb = 4;
   else if ( symbol == '5') symb =5 ;
   else if ( symbol == '6') symb =6 ;
   else if ( symbol == '7') symb =7;
   else if ( symbol == '8') symb =8 ;
   else if ( symbol == '9') symb =9 ;

   push(s,symb);
  }
   cin>>symbol;
 }
 value=pop(s);
 cout<<"The Value:: \n"<<value<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `break` after `return` statement?

Comment: You are entering the operand first (i.e., "/ 6 2.") you must enter the operand last (i.e., "6 2 /.")

Comment: it's just a Switch syntax!

Comment: Also you could check stack size after the evaluation, there should be only one element if the expression was correct. There is of course empty expression corner case to this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives the correct result for me:

```
6
2
/
.
The Value:: 
3
```

Note that you are having inversed polish notation, i.e. the operand must follow after the values to operate on.

Comment: Yes it does work when i put the operator after the two operands.I forgot it's a POSTFIX expression.